# gpg.exe Configuration on Windows

Tags: gnupg, encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

How gpg.exe is configured on windows? What is configuration for setting up the encryption and decryption?

Not sure how it is configured. Want to see where it is configuration and how the configuration looks like, any example will help.